# tkinter GUI blacked out screen after PyInstaller

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller

After I used PyInstaller on my script, containing tk GUI, the output GUI would show black screen. However, all my widgets are working. When I try to hover the mouse on the screen and try to press and interact with the GUI, it works.

So the GUI works perfectly however the screen is blacked out and I can't see anything.

Any idea how and why this happens? How to fix?

Code:

```
#main.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from parse_currency import CurrencyData
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import sys, os

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Currency Converter')
root.geometry('380x400')
root.config(bg='#122738')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


data = CurrencyData()




img_btn = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(resource_path('img/again.png')))
again_btn = tk.Button(root, image=img_btn)

logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(resource_path('img/icon_s.png')))

img_convert = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(resource_path('img/convert.png')))


def build_app():
    ''' * The App's widgets * '''
    #Titale 
    logo_l = tk.Label(
        root,
        image=logo
        )
    
    
    # From 
    from_l = tk.Label(
        root,
        text='From: ',
        bg='#122738',
        fg='#0090C5',
        font=('Times New Roman', 20, 'bold'))
    cur1 = tk.StringVar(value='Select currency')
    from_cur = tk.OptionMenu(root, cur1, *data.currencies)
    from_cur.config(bg='#122738', width=20)
    
    
    
    # To
    to_l = tk.Label(
        root, 
        text='To: ', 
        bg='#122738',
        fg='#0090C5', 
        font=('Times New Roman', 20, 'bold'))
    cur2 = tk.StringVar(value='Select currency')
    to_cur = tk.OptionMenu(root, cur2, *data.currencies)
    to_cur.config(bg='#122738', width=20)
    
    
    # Input
    num = tk.StringVar()
    num_e = tk.Entry(
        root,
        width=20,
        )
    
    # Convert
    convert_btn = tk.Button(root, image=img_convert)  
    
        
    # Result
    result_l = tk.Label(
        root,
        relief=tk.SUNKEN,
        justify=tk.CENTER, 
        width=20,
        bg='#f59abe',
        fg='blue',
        font=(
            'Times New Roman',
            20,
            'bold'
        )
        )
    
    ''' * Widgets Management * '''
    logo_l.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)
    from_l.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='w')
    from_cur.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='we', padx=10)
    to_l.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='w')
    to_cur.grid(row=6, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='we', padx=10)
    
    num_e.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)
    
    convert_btn.grid(row=99, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)
    result_l.grid(row=100, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)
    
    
    ''' * Logic and code * '''
    
    def convert():
        from_var = cur1.get()
        to_var = cur2.get()
        
        try:
            amount = float(num_e.get())
            from_index = data.currencies.index(from_var)
            to_index = data.currencies.index(to_var)
            
            d = amount*data.to_usd[from_index]
            r = d*data.from_usd[to_index] 
            if from_index == 0:
                r=amount*data.from_usd[to_index]
                
            if to_index == 0:
                r=amount*data.to_usd[from_index]
                
            result_l.config(text=round(r, 2))           

        except:
            mb.showerror(
            title='Invalid Input!',
            message='Please select your currencies.\nOr enter a valid value.')
    
    convert_btn.config(command=convert)
    
    


def rebuild():
    data.__init__()
    again_btn.grid_forget()
    check()
    
again_btn.config(command=rebuild)    
    
    

def check():
        
    if data.connect:
        build_app()
    else:
        mb.showerror(
            title='Failed to connect!',
            message='Could NOT connect to x-rates.com\nCheck internet connection!')
        
        
        again_btn.grid()
        
        
        
check()
root.mainloop()
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

class CurrencyData:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect = True
        try: 
            source = requests.get('https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1').text
        except:
            self.connect = False
            
            
        if self.connect:    
            soup = bs(source, 'lxml')
            table = soup.find_all('tbody')
            mini_data = table[1].find_all('tr')
            self.currencies = ['US Dollar']
            from_usd_str = ['1']
            to_usd_str = ['1']
            for currency in mini_data:
                self.currencies.append(currency.td.text)
                rates = currency.find_all('a')
                from_usd_str.append(rates[0].text)
                to_usd_str.append(rates[1].text)
            
            self.from_usd = [float(x) for x in from_usd_str]
            self.to_usd = [float(i) for i in to_usd_str]
```

Comment: So it is all black but there are still widgets that can be interacted with? ok, interesting, first of You could show Your actual code (which I assume works without everything being black), post it here in text format. Second I guess it would be helpful if You told whether You made that into a onefile or onedir?

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal to see error messages?

Comment: @Matiiss , Yes. Everything works when I run the code. I did onefile. My guess is because I used external images! I'll edit the post and add the code shortly.

Comment: @furas , yes and it works fine with no errors.

Comment: Ok, maybe try creating a onedir

Comment: @Matiiss I just did, same exact problem!

Answer (score 0):

From pyinstaller github issues: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5827

You can use this fork of pyinstaller: https://github.com/rokm/pyinstaller/tree/macos_sdk_11_to_darwin20

Install by cloning and running

`sudo python setup.py install`

Then using pyinstaller accordingly